# remove some character string from multiple filenames

Tags: replace, character, filenames

my OS is Win 10. i have a folder which contains files like: '**1.JPG.JPG.jpg**' or '**99.JPG.jpg**' or '**335.JPG.JPG.jpg**' -almost 470 files-
notice that the file names are look like value of ID column to reference and some files have 2 times '.JPG' but some have 1 time. also there are some files contains 'jpg' instead of 'JPG' (both without quotes) in between file name.
i want to rename all files with number value in start of file name and then add .jpg to all files like **1.jpg** or **99.jpg** or **335.jpg** etc. this is sure all files are jpeg, there is no .png or .bmp etc.
please help how i can do this?

EDIT: can i used to get digit part of file name and hard code .jpg and replace all file names at once using script, if yes, please guide how it can be done?

Comment: What tool are you using here?

Comment: nothing, i have just asked how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

its done using following Powershell commands searched from internet:

step 1) **ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".JPG.JPG",""}**

step 2) **ls | Rename-Item -NewName { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "jpg") }**

hope peoples like me (the novice) will get benefit.

**Link**: [https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#:~:text=You%20can%20press%20and%20hold,file%20to%20select%20a%20group](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#:%7E:text=You%20can%20press%20and%20hold,file%20to%20select%20a%20group).